# Does my "wouldn't' version make sense in my sentences?

Tags: meaning

Let's imagine a situation, suppose you are going to make a plan; stealing money from a house of a neighbour, in this plan you want me to involve in too. Now, you have just told me about this plan. But I Wouldn't want to steal money from a neighbour and so I wouldn't agree with you. I Wouldn't want to be a thief. Please don't make such a plan because I wouldn't agree with you and with this plan. I wouldn't want us to be arrested by police. Rather than stealing money, I would work hard and earn money. Does the "wouldn't" version make sense in my sentences?

Comment: "Wouldn't" is fine all the way through. I'm not sure what you mean by "vertion".

Comment: @MickSharpe Really? I recognized it immediately as a typographical error.

Comment: @yubrajsharma The sense of _wouldn't_ as emphasizing a negative desire is well demonstrated in these sentences. +1 ... However, it's hard to think of a useful answer other than a simple Yes."

Comment: @P.E Dent, is this "wouldn't" version called implied conditional ? Because there's is not any if clause.

Comment: @P.E Dent,I think this question itself answes the question of this question http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/94804/wouldnt-agree-vs-dont-agree Doesn't it ?

Comment: Please reply to my comment. .!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Each of your sentences has an implied if clause. For example, *(even) if  you asked me to* can be added to each sentence.

I wouldn't want to steal money from a neighbour, *(even) if  you asked me to*.

And  so I wouldn't agree with you, *(even) if  you asked me to*.

I wouldn't  want to be a thief, *(even) if  you asked me to*.

Please don't make such a plan because I wouldn't agree with you and with this plan, *(even) if  you asked me to*.

I  wouldn't want us to be arrested by police,  *(even) if  you asked me to*.